# How to manage multiple clients website having same code structure but different UI?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I want to create websites for many colleges using MVC.
Since coding structure will be common for all the client websites but the website templates will be different I need suggestions on handling this.
Do I need to create a core framework for this and use the same for other website projects? If I do so, then how do I handle the website template as these will be different.
Any opinion will be a great motivation for me to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a RestAPI, then use the endPoints to receive and send data.

> ```
>  WebServer -> www.colleges.com/user -> this give you all the
>  informations about users/students -> React framework to make the
>  Front-End.(React or other framework you like)
> ```

In this way you only have 1Webserver and multiple Front-End with the same information.